# how to retry with rxjs and execute a function after this

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to retry an api call 10 times (waiting one second since it fails until next execution) and if this 10 times it fails, then I will execute a function, this is my aproach:

```
private handleError(error, req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
  if (error.status === 0) {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(err => timer(1000).pipe(switchMapTo(this.checkConnection(err)))),
      retry(10)
    );
  } 
}

private checkConnection(error): Observable<any> {
   console.log(error)      
   return EMPTY;
}
```

This is not working, by using the provided solution regarding switch the order between retry and catch error, the timer stops working.

I also tried it with retryWhen:

```
if (error.status === 0) {
  return next.handle(req).pipe(
    retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(1000), take(10), 
    concatMapTo(this.checkConnection(errors)))));
}
```

Then my problem it's retried only once  and I have no the original error in my "checkConnection" function

What I can see by using console log is this is executed any try, and what I want to get is execute once it was executed 10 times.

I'm not able to find how to.

I'm using angular 8.

Based on the provided answer my code should work, but it does not, it has a compilation error, this is my full service:

```
import { throwError,  Observable , EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, delay, retryWhen, take, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  private handleError(error, req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
   if (error.status === 401) {
     this.router.navigate(['/login']);
     return EMPTY;  // Stops processing
   } else if (error.status === 403) {
     this.router.navigate(['/unauthorized']);
     return EMPTY;  // Stops processing
   }  else if (error.status === 0) {
      return next.handle(req).pipe(
        retryWhen((errors) => {
          return errors.pipe(
            delay(1000),
            take(10), // Number of retries
            concatMap(throwError)// Let the error bubble up again
          );
        }),
        catchError((err) => this.checkConnection(err)));
    }
   return throwError(error);
 }

 private checkConnection(error): Observable<any> {
   //it will have more logic in future, this is just the starting point to this function
   console.log(error)      
   return EMPTY;
 }

 constructor(private router: Router) {
 }

 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   return next.handle(req).pipe(
     catchError((error) => this.handleError(error, req, next))
   );
 }
```

}

Compilation error is

> Argument of type '(error: any, scheduler?: SchedulerLike) => Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => Observable'.
> Types of parameters 'scheduler' and 'index' are incompatible.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SchedulerLike'.

Answer (score 4):

`retry` should catch the inner error exactly N times. The N+1th time it will just pass it on as expected.
Currently you catch every error and pipe it to `checkConnection`.
Basically switching `retry` and `catchError` in your original example should already do the job.

```
    import {Observable, throwError, EMPTY} from 'rxjs';
    import {concatMap, delay, retryWhen, take} from 'rxjs/operators';

    private handleError(error, req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
      if (error.status === 0) {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
          retryWhen((errors) => {
            return errors.pipe(
              delay(1000),
              take(10), // Number of retries
              concatMap(throwError), // Let the error bubble up again
            )
          ),
          catchError((err) => this.checkConnection(err))),
        );
      } 
    }

    private checkConnection(error): Observable<any> {
       console.log(error)      
       return EMPTY;
    }
```

Comment: wow, I was completly confused on how it worked, but I think I still am confused, now what is not working is the delay of 1 seconds between the retries

Comment: Check out `retryWhen` if you want a delayed retry mechanism :)
I will provide an example in my answer.

Comment: i did, but not able to make it works! I edited my original post

Comment: I added it to my answer. Have a look, I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, but still not able to run... do you import throwError from rxjs? it creates a compilation error "argument of type '(error:any, scheduler?: SchedulerLike) => Observable<never> is not asignable to parameter of type (valuea:any, index:number) => OBservable<neverr>

Comment: I added the necessary imports to the post. Please double-check.

Comment: i really dont understand why my code is failing, this is exactly the same, i will update my post with full service

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have gone down a rabbit hole. You can try using the [repeat operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/repeat) since it’s designed to do exactly what you’re trying.

```
// RxJS v6+
import { repeat, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

const delayedThing = yourObservable.pipe(delay(2000));

delayedThing
  .pipe(repeat(3))
  // delayed value...delayed value...delayed value
  .subscribe(console.log);
```